# check circumflex character with Regexp

Tags: regex, symbols

I'm trying to check some special characters in a configuration file.

I'm able to check the following symbols :

- #
- $
- *
- &
- |

But I can't to parse the "^" symbol in my configuration file.  I tried with the following regexp :

`.*[(\^)].*` , `.*[("^")].*` , but it doesn't work...

I you have any idea to check that...  I'm using a specific language (similar to C Language).

Comment: What language are you using? Also, try removing the brackets and just using the character class with a masking backslash: `.*[\^].*`

Comment: I'm using 'hawk', a specific language, but based on M4 processor, and similar to C.  But like C, it's a compiled language, and compilation doesn't work with the pattern `.*[\^].*`   I tried with `.*[(\^)].*` ,   compilation works, but circumflex characters don't return errors.

Comment: If it is like C you should use: `.*[\\^].*`

Comment: I tried that : `.*\[\\#\\$\\*\\&\\|\\^\].*`  , it's ok for Compilation, but don't match anything...

Answer (score 0):

```
[#\$\*\&\|\^]
```

if you want to select the whole line containing any of these, then could use .* before after also:

```
.*[#\$\*\&\|\^].*
```

You may consider to use positive or negative look-ahead assertion:

```
^(?!.*[#\$\*\&\|\^]).*
```

https://regex101.com/r/zS1zM5/2